# Given $A$ and $B$ positive-definite matrices and $Q$ unitary matrix, prove that if $A = BQ$, then $A=B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $A$ and $B$ positive-definite matrices and $Q$ unitary matrix, prove that if $A = BQ$, then $A=B$.

$Q$ is unitary, so $QQ^*=I$

If $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite, than $A=A^*$ and $B=B^*$.

$A^*=(BQ)^*=Q^*B^*$

$A^2=AA=AA^*=(BQ)(Q^*B^*)=B(QQ^*)B^*=BIB^*=B^2$

$A^2=B^2$.

I don't know how to use the fact that $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite to finish the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: By considering $x^\ast Ax$ for each eigenvector $x$ of $Q$, show that $Q=I$.

Comment: can you please extend the hint?

Comment: @rotemb At some point in following reasoning my idea and user1551's diverge. Let $(x,\lambda)$ be an eigenpair of $Q$. Then $x^*Ax=\lambda x^*Bx$. Since $A$ and $B$ are  positive-definite, it follows that $x^*Ax$ and $x^*Bx$ are positive real numbers. So $\lambda$ is too. But $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of an unitary matrix. What does this tell you about lambda? How do $A$ and $B$ related knowing this and what does that relationship entail?

Comment: @rotemb Git Gud's comment almost says it all. In additional, note that $Q$ is a normal matrix, so it has an eigenbasis.

Comment: Is is possible to prove the claim without using the fact that $Q$ is  diagonalizable?

Comment: @Jneven You may continue with the OP's work. Since every positive semidefinite matrix has a unique positive semidefinite square root, if $A^2=B^2$, then $A=(A^2)^{1/2}=(B^2)^{1/2}=B$.